# Jquery not display id on page

Tags: jquery, html

The query returned from the database has data but it does not echo out on the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$('#faults').click(function(){ 
    var fault_id =('input[name=faults]:checked', '#faults').val(); 
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/Repair/find_workdone_list/"+fault_id,

    success: function(cities) {
    $.each(cities,function(id,work){
    $('#workdone').append("<input type='radio' id='workdone' name='workdone' value='" + id + "'>" + work + "<br>");

      });
     }
    });
 });
});
```

This is my html code on the page

```
<div id="workdone"></div>
```

Please help what am i missing here ?

Comment: You're missing a `$` - `var fault_id = $('input[name="faults"]:checked', '#faults').val();`

Comment: Btw, having many DOM elements with the same id (`workdone` in your case) is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, missing a `$` at:

```
var fault_id = $('input[name=faults]:checked', '#faults').val();
```

I assume you have a json to iterate it as an array. Add JSON type to the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/Repair/find_workdone_list/"+fault_id,

    success: function(cities) {
    $.each(cities,function(id,work){
    $('#workdone').append("<input type='radio' id='workdone' name='workdone' value='" + id + "'>" + work + "<br>");

      });
     }
 });
```

If it is XML that you are passing then instead of JSON write XML. If it still doesn't work then check your encoding at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)